# Simplification of expression involving least squares estimators

Tags: least-squares, hessian

Consider the sum of squared residuals of a linear regression given by

$$ S_i(a,b) = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-a-bx_i)^2$$

I have to show that the optimal values of $a$ and $b$ found using the first-order conditions do indeed minimize $S_i(a,b)$. After some calculations, we find that the Hessian matrix is

$$ H = \begin{bmatrix} 2n & 2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \\ 2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i & 2\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Now, $2n > 0$. So it remains to show

$$ 4 \cdot \left(n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2\right) > 0 $$

Looking online I found that

$$ \left(n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2\right) = n \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})^2 > 0$$

where $\bar{x}$ is the mean. I can't see how to go from the expression on the left to the one on the right.

I'd appreciate it if someone could explain it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go from the right to the left.

\begin{align}
n\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2 &= n\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i^2-2\bar{x} x_i +\bar{x}^2)\\&= n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-2n\bar{x} \sum_{i=1}^nx_i  + n^2 \bar{x}^2 \\
&= n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-2n^2\bar{x} \left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{n} \right) + n^2 \bar{x}^2 \\
&=n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2- n^2 \bar{x}^2 \\
\end{align}

I will leave the last step for you to simplify.

By the way, the conclusion should be nonnegative rather than positive.

---

Alternatively, here is an approach in terms of matrices, we want to minimize

$$L(\|A\tilde{z}-y\|^2$$ where $A$ include a column of $1$ to handle the intercept term and $\tilde{z}$ include the intercept term as well.

Differentiate it, we obtain $$\nabla_z(L)=A^T(A\tilde{x}-y)$$

and $$\nabla_z^2(L)=A^TA \succeq 0$$

Comment: Thanks for answering. I understand how we can go from "right to left", but in order to do that we'd need previous knowledge of the equality of both expressions. Could you show me how to go from "left to right"?  Also, thanks for pointing out that it should be nonnegative. For it to be positive we need $x_i \neq \bar{x}$ for some $i$

Comment: If you can write down something from right to left, to write from left to right, read it from the backward direction. Also, That is just the two alternative expression of variance right?

Comment: Could you detail what the steps would be to go from the expression on the right of the second line to the one on the right of the first line?

Comment: We have $nc=\sum_{i=1}^n c$,  here $c=\bar{x}^2$ and then you factorize $n$ out from each term